# If picked file name have no extensions, how we will get file mime type in flutter

Tags: flutter, file, mime-types, file-type, filepicker

I'm using file picker for my application. In that, I want to know picked file mime type even file name has no extension. How it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

use this package [mime](https://pub.dev/packages/mime)

You can get mime type from file path like this:

```
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
....
lookupMimeType(file.path) // output: Image/Jpeg
```

Comment: I have no file extensions in my file name. File name should be like this "test". not "test.jpeg".

Comment: @Maheswari please read this https://github.com/dart-lang/mime#determining-the-mime-type-for-a-file. if no extensions found, it will determine the mime type from the magic bytes in the beginning of the file

Comment: @HasilT How can I find the mime type of pdf file that doesn't have a .pdf extension on the filename?? headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8] always return mime type as image/jpeg, so how is it possible to identify a document without any extension ??